# How to balance between two arrays such as the difference is minimized?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have an array `A[]={3,2,5,11,17}` and `B[]={2,3,6}`, size of B is always less than A. Now I have to map from every element B to *distinct* elements of A such that the total difference `sum( abs(Bi-Aj) )` becomes minimum (Where Bi has been mapped to Aj). What is the type of algorithm?

For the example input, I could select, `2->2=0` , `3->3=0` and then `6->5=1`. So the total cost is 0+0+1 = 1. I have been thinking sorting both the arrays and then take the first `sizeof B` elements from the A. Will this work?

Comment: Try your idea on `A = {1,2,3,4}` and `B = {3,4}` and see if it works.

Comment: No It doesn't work.. :( what should I do? I have another thinking. take every permutation of A with B elements, then try to match the elements. But in my problem, A can be upto 200 and B upto 50 giving 1.38036910e+112 permutaitons, which is infeasible. How Do I solve it than?

Comment: This is probably a much harder problem. Correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't you solve Subset Sum using only O(n) instances of this problem? Make B contain only zeroes, and test for every possible subset-size (`n` of them) whether the total difference is zero or not (O(n) to get that total difference). So, if you could do that in some polynomial time M, then you could solve SubsetSum in O(M * n^2)

Comment: @harold Depends whether the elements are all positive or not. If they're all positive, for the zero case, you just end up picking the minimum elements from A.

Comment: the elements are all positive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be thought of as an unbalanced [Assignment Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).

The cost matrix shall be the difference in values of B[i] and A[j]. You can add dummy elements to B so that the problem becomes balanced and put the costs associated very high.

Then [Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) can be applied to solve it.

For the example case A[]={3,2,5,11,17} and B[]={2,3,6} the cost matrix shall be:

```
.   3  2  5 11 17
2   1  0  3  9 15
3   0  1  2  8 14
6   3  4  1  5 11
d1 16 16 16 16 16
d2 16 16 16 16 16
```

Comment: The hungarian algorithm is too complex for me to understand, can you give a useful link?

Comment: This link explains the algorithm in simple steps. http://www.wikihow.com/Use-the-Hungarian-Algorithm

Comment: How to do step 5 ? Cover the zero elements with the minimum number of lines it is possible to cover them with. (If the number of lines is equal to the number of rows then go to step 9)

Comment: @TamimAdDari Yes, this step is a bit complicated. This link tries to explain the steps. http://www.universalteacherpublications.com/univ/ebooks/or/Ch6/hungalgo.htm